# GridColumnGroupingModel MUI issue

Tags: typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I hava an issue with column grouping in MUI data grid pro. I am working with typescript and i want to implement column grouping, however I run into the issue with the module GridColumnGroupingModel, which is used as type definition for columnGroupingModel. As per examples on MUI docs i am trying to import it from data-grid-pro, as seen below:

`import { GridColumnGroupingModel } from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro"`

Unfortunately I receive and error:

Module '"@mui/x-data-grid-pro"' has no exported member 'GridColumnGroupingModel'.

The installed version of @mui/x-data-grid-pro on the project is 5.12.2, however the same problem exists on 5.16.0.

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

@AdamJJ. You might have missing the peer dependencies. Try adding them to your package.json and run npm i.